# Printing tensor containing more than 10 columns in Luajit/ torch

Tags: torch, luajit

I want to print a tensor of dimension 2 X 11 in console.

print(tensor) is printing like this

Columns 1 to 10

0.2660  0.1791  0.1237  0.0558  0.0810  0.0284  0.0103  0.1185  0.0811  0.0258

0.1408  0.2460  0.1186  0.0831  0.1497  0.0297  0.0094  0.0658  0.1364  0.0071

Columns 11 to 11

0.0302

0.0135

[torch.FloatTensor of size 11x11]

I want to print all like this:

0.2660  0.1791  0.1237  0.0558  0.0810  0.0284  0.0103  0.1185  0.0811  0.0258 0.0302

0.1408  0.2460  0.1186  0.0831  0.1497  0.0297  0.0094  0.0658  0.1364  0.0071 0.0135

Comment: I want to print all matrix value like 10 rows 11 column

Answer (score 0):

This is torch `print` function default behavior. A quick and dirty way to change that would be the following

```
for i = 1, my_tensor:size(1) do
    line = ''
    for j = 1, my_tensor:size(2) do
        line = line .. my_tensor[i][j] .. '\t'
    end
    print(line)
end
```